# Twitter Bootstrap html templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use one of the twitter bootstrap templates in the link below for my website but I don't know how to get the code. Here's the link :  [HTML Template](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#html-template)

Is there a way to use those templates?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to copy-paste? Or do you have some other problem that you have left out from your question?

Comment: View source. Copy/paste. Or save as html.

Comment: This seems, more than anything, to be a really core misunderstanding of how webpages/html works.

Comment: Never mind, I thought I can get the code somewhere from the website besides from clicking :VIew Source" and copying.

Comment: @Colleen, its been 3 days now and I am struggling to buildwell desinged HTML navigation bar and a well desinged website layout. That's why I am looking for a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the source of the latest examples on github :

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/examples

Or any versions of those by browsing the tags :

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tags

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/twitter-bootstrap-101-introduction/

Hope this helps